# Toggle "Announce the Time" when presenting?

Tags: macos, automation, time, speech

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303113/13096) shows how to programmatically toggle "Announce the time", but how can I automatically trigger this when I dis/connect from/to (certain) external displays?